# Create Query on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable `$z_name=carredwidetastymodern...;` (here I show just a part of string "opelmazdabmwhynday..." (in fact, it's a very long string) 
I would like fill in `ref` field from $z_name, could anybody help me?

```
id  name   ref    id  name     ref 

10  opel          10  opel     car
11  apple         11  apple    red
12  river         12  river    wide
13  food          13  food     tasty
14  pc            14  pc       modern
```

(here I show just a part of table. It's a very big table, a lot of records)

Comment: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-insert-statement.htm and/or http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-update-statement.htm

Comment: how would you know till where to chunk the string and insert the chunk?

Answer (score 2):

Use loop by all records and add inside
    mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET ref = '$z_name' WHERE id =$id");

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe I'm missing something... I would say that

```
"REPLACE INTO table_name SET ref = '" . $z_name . "'";
```

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` seems to be a very unstable way to update a record. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10795 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/432857/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/404240/1415724 - using `INSERT` or `UPDATE` would probably be a safer bet.